# ListView error from SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, populate

I have a problem and do not know what to do. I'm trying to create a ListView from the SQLite database, but the application causes an error in the database. I've tried several things but it did not work. One thing to note is that the application works perfectly on my smartphone (Android 4.4.4), but gives error in other diferents this version.
I will be grateful if you can send me this information.

**LogCat**

```
12-11 09:16:41.860: W/EGL_emulation(1101): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-11 09:16:47.280: E/SQLiteLog(1101): (1) no such table: medidas
12-11 09:16:47.290: D/AndroidRuntime(1101): Shutting down VM
12-11 09:16:47.310: W/dalvikvm(1101): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0xb1a8bba8)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101): Process: com.bodyevolution, PID: 1101
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate  activity ComponentInfo{com.bodyevolution/com.bodyevolution.ConsultarMedidasActivity}:  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: medidas (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT *  FROM medidas WHERE id_usuario = ?
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: medidas (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM medidas WHERE id_usuario = ?
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.bodyevolution.usuario.persistencia.UsuarioDAO.findMedidasById(UsuarioDAO.java:101)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.bodyevolution.usuario.negocio.UsuarioBusiness.datasMedidas(UsuarioBusiness.java:70)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at com.bodyevolution.ConsultarMedidasActivity.<init>(ConsultarMedidasActivity.java:15)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
12-11 09:16:47.450: E/AndroidRuntime(1101):     ... 11 more
```

**DB code**

```
package com.bodyevolution.bd;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private final static int VERSAO = 1;
private final static String NOME = "bodyevolution.sqlite";
private static final String CREATE_USUARIO = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuario ("
        + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + "username VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL, "
        + "senha VARCHAR( 6 ) NOT NULL, "
        + "nome VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL, "
        + "sexo VARCHAR ( 10 ), "
        + "data VARCHAR ( 10 ));";

private static final String CREATE_MEDIDAS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS medidas ("
        + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + "id_usuario INTEGER, "
        + "data VARCHAR (10), "
        + "bracos DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "peitoral DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "coxas DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "costas DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "panturrilhas DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "trapezio DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "antebracos DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "cintura DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "peso DECIMAL(2,1), "
        + "altura DECIMAL(1,2));";

private static final String CREATE_TREINO = "";
private static final String CREATE_EXERCICIO = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USUARIO);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_MEDIDAS);
}

public BD(Context context) {
    super(context, NOME, null, VERSAO);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_USUARIO);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_MEDIDAS);

    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

**Methods that return information to ListView**

```
public List<Medidas> findMedidasById(int id){
    List<Medidas> medidas = new ArrayList<Medidas>();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + this.getMEDIDAS() + " WHERE id_usuario = ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "" + id };
    Cursor cursor = bancodedados.rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        medidas.add(montaMedidas(cursor));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    return medidas;
}



public Medidas montaMedidas(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    Double bracos = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("bracos"));
    Double peitoral = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("peitoral"));
    Double coxas = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("coxas"));
    Double costas = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("costas"));
    Double panturrilha = cursor.getDouble(cursor
            .getColumnIndex("panturrilhas"));
    Double trapezio = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("trapezio"));
    Double antebracos = cursor.getDouble(cursor
            .getColumnIndex("antebracos"));
    Double cintura = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("cintura"));
    Double peso = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("peso"));
    Double altura = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("altura"));
    String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));

    Medidas medidas = new Medidas();

    medidas.setBracos(bracos);
    medidas.setPeitoral(peitoral);
    medidas.setCoxas(coxas);
    medidas.setCostas(costas);
    medidas.setPanturrilha(panturrilha);
    medidas.setTrapezio(trapezio);
    medidas.setAntebracos(antebracos);
    medidas.setCintura(cintura);
    medidas.setPeso(peso);
    medidas.setAltura(altura);
    medidas.setData(data);

    return medidas;
}
```

**Activity code**

```
package com.bodyevolution;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.bodyevolution.usuario.dominio.Medidas;
import com.bodyevolution.usuario.negocio.UsuarioBusiness;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ConsultarMedidasActivity extends Activity {

UsuarioBusiness usuarioBusiness = new UsuarioBusiness();
List<Medidas> retornaListaMedidas = usuarioBusiness.datasMedidas();

List<String> datas = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consultar_medidas);

    for (Medidas m : retornaListaMedidas) {
        datas.add(m.getData());
    }

    ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDatasMedidas);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datas);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Comment: So what happend when you stepped trough your code? Specifically at the DB.onCreate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception thrown is

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table:
>   medidas (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM medidas WHERE
>   id_usuario = ?

So your 'medidas' table does not exist. So please verify that `onCreate` is called and the call of `db.execSQL(CREATE_MEDIDAS);`

Furthermore:

```
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_USUARIO);
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_MEDIDAS);
```

it should be the name of the table, not the whole create statement.

Also your note that SQLite has no `Decimal`, it will be a `REAL`

Comment: Thanks for answering. I made all the changes you told me, but still the same error.